Power Query - Replace value based on a specific combination
Sorry for the poor title, I'm struggling to put into words what I need and I am a beginner with Power Query.
Basically, I have a selection of Price Sub Groups where the NPTR is incorrect and I need them to specifically reflect the NPTR that the On Premise Price Sub Group has. In the example, I thought I would create a custom column for this, but I can't figure out how to reference specifically the NPTR of a single Price Sub Group instead of an entire column of values.
There are many products so it's not just the one specific static cell either.

Here's what I tried, but it is not specific enough. I don't need NPTR in general, I need the On Premise NPTR.
= Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "Custom", each if List.Contains ({"TIER I", "TIER II", "LEGACY I", "LEGACY II", "AIRPORT", "CONCESSIONS"},[Price Sub Group]) then **[NPTR]** else [FPTR])


So you want the NPTR value that corresponds to On Premise Price to replace the current NPTR value for any of the Price Sub Groups in your list?

@bugdrown yes that's exactly correct

Given your limited sample, possibly:
if List.Contains ({"TIER I", "TIER II", "LEGACY I", "LEGACY II", "AIRPORT", "CONCESSIONS"},[Price Sub Group]) 
    then Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Price Sub Group] = "ON PREMISE")[NPTR]{0}
    else [FPTR]

However, you might want to do this within a Table.Group aggregation depending on what your data really looks like.

Thanks for your reply - I think I am doing something incorrectly because it's giving me an error for all of the Price Sub Groups in the list when I tried this.

@SecretDuckie Possibly. But since you did not post sufficient data for me to reproduce your problem, I can't help you further. I suggest you edit your question after reading the HELP pages for information as to How to Ask a Good Question, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and also Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?.

I'm sorry, I didn't intend to be obtuse or fail to include enough information. I tried reading your links above but I'm still not sure how to better clarify. I did make sure to still include the code in addition to the image. I am not getting an error code or anything, it just shows "Error" on those specific Price Sub Groups in the new column. I appreciate you trying to help despite my inability to express myself well.

@SecretDuckie Edit your question to include a representative data sample as text which can be copy/pasted and a screenshot of your desired results from that data. Your code can be found if you open the Advanced Editor. The data can be made up so as not to reveal any confidential information, but must be representative.
